# Rails 3 Asset Pipeline: JQuery Datepicker is working, but Timepicker will not work at all

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

The javascript console is giving me this error for any of the timepickers I've tried to integrate, **though it does work fine for datepicker**. Also datetimepicker doesn't work.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'timePicker'
```

I have tried a number of different timepicker libraries and none of them work.

Here is my application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require bootstrap-timepicker
//= require jquery.timePicker
//= require jquery.timePicker.min
//= require schools
```

My application.css file:

```
*= require_self
*= require jquery.ui.all
*= require bootstrap_and_overrides
*= require formtastic-bootstrap
*= require formtastic_changes
*= require bootstrap-datepicker
*= require bootstrap-timepicker
*= require gmaps4rails
*= require schools
*= require timePicker
```

My Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'therubyracer', '~> 0.10.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'jquery-rails'
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
  gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
end

gem 'sextant'
gem 'passenger'
gem 'formtastic', " ~> 2.1.1"
gem 'formtastic-bootstrap'
gem 'country_select'
gem 'slim'
gem 'redcarpet'
gem "auto_html"
gem 'gmaps4rails'
gem 'friendly_id'
gem 'devise'

gem 'capistrano'
gem 'unicorn'

gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
gem "bootstrap-timepicker-rails"

gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

My schools.js file ('datepicker' is highlighted pink and 'timePicker' is highlighted brown. If I change 'timePicker' to anything other than 'datepicker', it stays brown):

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $('#date_picker').datepicker();
  $('.time_picker').timePicker();
});
```

My view:

```
<% if current_user %>
  <h3>Create Reminder</h3>
  <%= form_tag create_user_reminder_path, method: 'post' do %>
    <%= select_datetime Time.now, :prompt => :date  %>
    <%= text_field_tag :date, nil, :id => "date_picker" %>
    <div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker-component">
      <%= text_field_tag :time, nil, :class => "time_picker input-small" %>
      <span class="add-on">
          <i class="icon-time"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
    <%= text_area_tag :message %>
    <% if @school %>
      <% unless @school.id == current_user.school_id %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :school_id, @school.id %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= submit_tag 'Save Reminder' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: If you remove all references to timepicker (jquery and bootstrap) in your `application.js` and `Gemfile`, just keep `//= require jquery.timePicker` in your application.js, and then do a `bundle update` does this work? It looks like something is getting over-ridden..

Comment: Make sure you remove the `//= require jquery.timePicker.min` as well

Answer (score 0):

Is it not `$('.time_picker').timepicker();` instead of `$('.time_picker').timePicker();` ?

(Note the small 'p' in timepicker)